# viewport doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'm in trouble with setting 100% width for body when I brows the page with smart phone.
viewport setting is

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"
```

console shows the sizes like

> screen.width= 320 
>  screen.availWidth= 320 
>  window.innerWidth=
>   975 
>  window.outerWidth= 320 
>  $(window).width()= 320 
>   document.documentElement.clientWidth= 320
>  document.width= 975
>    $(document).width()= 975 
>  $('body').width()= 970

and I added 'width:975px' to body's css. 
Then console shows the sizes below

> screen.width= 320
>  screen.availWidth= 320
>  window.innerWidth=
>   977
>  window.outerWidth= 320
>  $(window).width()= 320
>   document.documentElement.clientWidth= 320
>  document.width= 977
>   $(document).width()= 977
>  $('body').width()= 975

I want to set body's width same as document's width.
Would someone know how I can fix this?

Comment: did you remove the margins on the body? `html,body{margin:0}`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the meta tag with the 'initial-scale' property?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining initial-scale and maximun-scale

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And reset margins and padding in the body in your css:

```
html,body{margin:0, padding:0}
```